# Recursive function to return each character in Input

Tags: javascript, recursion

i am trying to use recursion to return each character in a string. However, the output is not

```
//We define a function with input parameter.
function countCharInString(string) {
  //vi Define an empty objec 
  const result = {};
  //we loop through the length of string
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) { 
    //create another variable for each element in string
    const ch = string[i];
    //BASE CASE: if string is empty, return Object with nothing 
    if (!result[ch]) {
      return result[ch]=0;
    } else {
      //RECURSION: 1 plus whatever the length of the substring from the next character onwards is
      return countCharInString(result[ch] + 1)
    }  
  }
}
console.log(countCharInString("Vi skal tælle bogstaver"))
```

the output should be the following:

```
var result = {
l : 3,
a : 2,
e : 2,
s : 2,
t : 2,
v : 2,
b: 1,
i : 1,
k : 1,
o : 1,
r : 1,
æ : 1
};
```

Comment: Your function expects a string for its parameter. `countCharInString(result[ch] + 1)` looks completely wrong for that. Also, you never `return` the object you're building.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this with a loop instead of recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would suggest to do it with a simple reduce like so

```js
var inputString = 'donald duck';
var result = inputString.split('').reduce((acc, char, index) => {
    if (acc[char] !== undefined) {
      acc[char] = acc[char] + 1;
  }
  else {
    acc = { ...acc, [char]: 1 }
  }
  return acc
}, {})
```

see: https://jsfiddle.net/yswu91zh/21/

Answer (score 0):

Only recursion would not give you the output that you are asking for. After recursively counting character you have to sort it by frequency and then by character. I have excluded a bunch of punctuation with space from counting, if you want exclude more just add it to the punctuation string. You have to use `String.prototype.localeCompare()` method to compare the characters. This method compares two strings in the current locale. As you are using Danish language you have to specify locale as `da`.

```js
const punctuations = '.,:;!? ';
const countCharInString = (str, p = {}) => {
  if (str.length === 0) return p;
  const key = str[0].toLowerCase();
  if (!punctuations.includes(key)) {
    if (!p[key]) p[key] = 1;
    else p[key] += 1;
  }
  return countCharInString(str.slice(1), p);
};

const cmp = (x, y) => {
  if (x[1] === y[1]) {
    return x[0].localeCompare(y[0], 'da');
  }
  return x[1] < y[1] ? 1 : -1;
};
const ret = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(countCharInString('Vi skal tælle bogstaver')).sort(cmp)
);
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: I have updated the code. Now it is giving the same output as yours.